# Как посчитать количество элементов в определенном блоке div? JS

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Как можно посчитать количество элементов в определенном блоке?

```
$(".img_block_coll img").length
```

считает все `.img_block_coll img` на странице, а мне нужно почитать для каждого блока `.product`, и скрыть остальные `img` если их количество больше 2-х.

```
<div class="product">
   <div class="img_block">
      <img>
      <img>
      <img> 
   </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
   <div class="img_block">
      <img>
      <img>
      <img>
      <img>
      <img>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `$($('.product')[0]).find('.img_block_coll img').lenfth` - поиск в первом блоке с классом `product`

Comment: спасибо, но нужно пройтись по всем блокам product и посчитать кол-во

Comment: засуньте этот код в цикл с итерацией по индексу вместо `[0]` - это базовые знания js. Хотя в этом случае я решительно не понимаю в чем отличие от селектора `.product .img_block_coll img`

Comment: map() помогло
$(".img_block_coll").map(function() {
                var col = $(this).find('img').length;
                console.log(col);
              });

Answer (score 2):

```js
$(document).on('click', '.product', function (e) {
  console.log($(this).find(".img_block img").length)
})
```

```css
.product {
  margin: 1em;
  border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="product">
  <div class="img_block">
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <div class="img_block">
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
    <img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Для этой задачи можно не считать длину, а использовать CSS псевдокласс, например, `nth-of-type`
`.img_block > img:nth-of-type(n+3)` этот селектор расшифровывается так:
в элементе с классом `.img_block` на первой уровне вложенности найти все теги `img`, начиная с третьего элемента(вместо n подставляется 0, 1, 2 и т.д.)

на CSS:

```css
.img_block > img:nth-of-type(n+3) {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="product">
   <div class="img_block">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
   <div class="img_block">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
   </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
const img_to_remove = document.querySelectorAll('.img_block > img:nth-of-type(n+3)');

img_to_remove.forEach((item) => item.remove());
```

```html
<div class="product">
   <div class="img_block">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
   </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
   <div class="img_block">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
      <img src="https://i.picsum.photos/id/974/200/300.jpg?hmac=QEuRqsjG8spkqu72dWfkl4m-kSl5p-CEfHgx9dnnZLo">
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Данная функция перебирает каждый из блоков `product`, проверяя в них количество элементов `img`, и если их больше двух, то скрывает их:

```js
function handleClick() {
  $(".product").each(function() {
    const $imgs = $(this).find("img")
    if ($imgs.length > 2) {
      $imgs.hide()
    }
  })
}

$("button").on("click", handleClick)
```

```css
button {
  margin-top: 20px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="product">
  <p>Block 1</p>
  <div class="img_block">
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p>Block 2</p>
  <div class="img_block">
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
  </div>
</div>
<div class="product">
  <p>Block 3</p>
  <div class="img_block">
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
    <img src="https://hhh.com" />
  </div>
</div>

<button>Hide if more than two</button>
```